# Set sender email address in frontend using Solspace Freeform (v4)

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm trying to make a form, using the free version of Solspace Freeform (v4). And I would like to set the "from" field in the email.

```
{exp:freeform:form form_id="2" required="message|email|recipient_email" recipient_user_input="yes" recipient_user_limit="1" recipient_user_template="original" }

    <fieldset class="message">

        <legend>Your personal message</legend>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Hello..."></textarea>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="emails">

        <label for="email">Your email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email@example.com" />

        <label for="recipient_email_user">Receivers email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="recipient_email_user" id="recipient_email_user" placeholder="email@example.com" />

    </fieldset>

{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In your notification template (in this case, the one called "original", just put `{email}` in the "From" field.

OR, perhaps even better, use an email address originating from your domain (say, `website@yourdomain.com`) in "From", and use `{email}` as the "Reply-To" address. (This will help with deliverability, as some servers may reject email which is from an address that does not originate on the sending domain.)